# How can I get the same object back (pass by reference) when calling C++ code from Python (using ctypes)?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am trying to interoperate between Python and C++.

This is my C++ code for a test DLL method:

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) PEParserNamespace::PEParserBase& _cdecl test(PEParserNamespace::PEParserBase* base) {
    printf("the C++ function was called\n");
    base->bytes = 12345;
    return *base;
}
```

I try to use it from Python like so:

```py
import ctypes
#DataStructures.py
class PEParserBase(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("hFile", ctypes.c_void_p),
        ("dwFileSize", ctypes.c_ulong),
        ("bytes", ctypes.c_ulong),
        ("fileBuffer",ctypes.c_void_p)]
class PEHEADER(ctypes.Structure):
    xc = 0
#FunctionWrapper.py
def testWrapper(peParserBase, _instanceDLL):
    _instanceDLL.test.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(PEParserBase)]
    _instanceDLL.test.restype = PEParserBase
    return _instanceDLL.test(ctypes.byref(pEParserBase))

pEParserBase = PEParserBase()
print("hallo welt")
_test = ctypes.CDLL('PeParserPythonWrapper.dll')

print(id(testWrapper(pEParserBase, _test)))
print(id(pEParserBase))
```

I expected that `testWrapper` to return the original `PEParserBase` instance, but it doesn't - the reported `id` values are different. The C++ code doesn't create any new instances of `PEParserBase` or anything else, so I'm confident the problem has to be in the Python code.

Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You can replace `id` by `ctypes.adressof` for comparing. If you really need identity here, you must keep a dict mapping the address to the Python object and write functions to manage this dict.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is fine if your English is not native, but please still try to write about **the problem, not** yourself - and try to ask a clear question, directly, and without conversation. I edited the post to fix the writing, and to meet site standards. For more information, please read [ask] and [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950).

Comment: @MichaelButscher seems worth writing up as an answer (including an explanation for why it doesn't work as-is; I assume there is some kind of implicit copy involved in crossing a DLL boundary, or something like that?), if there is no applicable duplicate (definitely not my field of expertise, so I can't easily search for one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id()` in CPython returns the address of the Python `ctypes` wrapper object, not the address of the object wrapped.  For that, use `ctypes.addressof()`.

`ctypes` also only understands C plain old data (POD) types and structures.  It doesn't know C++ namespaces or references, but since references are really C++ syntactic sugar for pointers, you can use a pointer in `.argtypes` and `.restype` as a replacement.

Here's a minimal example:

**test.cpp**

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

namespace PEParserNamespace {
struct PEParserBase {
    void* hFile;
    unsigned long dwFileSize;
    unsigned long bytes;
    void* fileBuffer;
};
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
PEParserNamespace::PEParserBase& _cdecl test(PEParserNamespace::PEParserBase* base) {
    printf("the C++ function was called\n");
    base->bytes = 12345;
    return *base;
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

class PEParserBase(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (("hFile", ct.c_void_p),
                ("dwFileSize", ct.c_ulong),
                ("bytes", ct.c_ulong),
                ("fileBuffer",ct.c_void_p))

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.test.argtypes = ct.POINTER(PEParserBase),
dll.test.restype = ct.POINTER(PEParserBase)    # Use a pointer here for the reference

base = PEParserBase()
pbase = dll.test(ct.byref(base))

print(hex(ct.addressof(base)), base.bytes)
print(hex(ct.addressof(pbase.contents)), base.bytes)  # .contents dereferences the pointer
                                                  # so we get the address of the structure
                                                  # not the address of the pointer itself.
```

Output:

```
the C++ function was called, base=00000169712ADAF0
0x169712adaf0 12345
0x169712adaf0 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

You have ***U**ndefined **B**ehavior* (actually a bunch of them):

- ***C**Types* (as the name suggests) works with ***C***. A ***reference*** is a ***C++*** specific concept (***C*** knows nothing about it)
- Due to the fact that a reference is actually a memory address (just like a pointer, **but with some key differences**), your *Python* function prototype (***restype***) is incorrect. Check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for more details.
  Note: specifying a pointer instead would do the trick, but it's still technically incorrect (if one wants to be rigorous)

*CTypes* objects are *Python* wrappers ([[Python.Docs]: Common Object Structures - type PyObject](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject)) over the actual *C* ones.
[[Python.Docs]: Built-in Functions - id(object)](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id) returns the address of **the *Python* wrapper object** (which is different than the wrapped's).
Instead, you should use ***ctypes.addressof***.

I prepared a small example (I defined the *C* structure based on the *Python* one and member names - also drawn the conclusion that you're on *Win* (but all the ideas in the answer are *OS* agnostic)).

- *dl00.cpp*:

  ```cpp
  #include <stdio.h>

  #if defined(_WIN32)
  #  include <Windows.h>
  #  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
  #  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
  #endif


  struct PEParserBase {
      HANDLE hFile;
      DWORD dwFileSize;
      ULONG bytes;
      LPVOID fileBuffer;
  };

  typedef PEParserBase *PPEParserBase;


  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  extern "C" {
  #endif

  DLL00_EXPORT_API PPEParserBase func00ptr(PPEParserBase parg);

  #if defined(__cplusplus)
  }
  #endif


  PPEParserBase func00ptr(PPEParserBase parg)
  {
      printf("  C:\n    Address: 0x%0zX\n", reinterpret_cast<size_t>(parg));
      if (parg) {
          printf("    dwFileSize: %u\n    bytes: %u\n", parg->dwFileSize, parg->bytes);
          parg->dwFileSize = 123;
      }
      return parg;
  }
  ```
- *code00.py*:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import ctypes as cts
  import ctypes.wintypes as wts
  import sys


  DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")


  class PEParserBase(cts.Structure):
      _fields_ = (
          ("hFile", wts.HANDLE),
          ("dwFileSize", wts.DWORD),
          ("bytes", wts.ULONG),
          ("fileBuffer", wts.LPVOID),
      )

      def __str__(self):
          ret = [self.__repr__()]
          for field, _ in self._fields_:
              ret.append("  {:s}: {:}".format(field, getattr(self, field)))
          return "\n".join(ret)

  PEParserBasePtr = cts.POINTER(PEParserBase)


  def print_ctypes_obj(obj):
      _id = id(obj)
      try:
          _addrof = cts.addressof(obj)
      except TypeError:
          _addrof = 0
      print("Id: 0x{:016X}\nAddressOf: 0x{:016X}\n{:s}\n".format(_id, _addrof, str(obj)))


  def main(*argv):
      dll = cts.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
      func00ptr = dll.func00ptr
      func00ptr.argtypes = (PEParserBasePtr,)
      func00ptr.restype = PEParserBasePtr

      use_ptr = 1
      if use_ptr:
          print("Test pointer export\n")
          pb0 = PEParserBase(None, 3141593, 2718282, None)
          print_ctypes_obj(pb0)
          ppb0 = cts.byref(pb0)
          print_ctypes_obj(ppb0)
          ppb1 = func00ptr(ppb0)
          print()
          print_ctypes_obj(ppb1)
          pb1 = ppb1.contents
          print_ctypes_obj(pb1)


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                     64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
      rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
      print("\nDone.\n")
      sys.exit(rc)
  ```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q075885080]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 > nul
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL dll00.cpp  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll
> dll00.cpp
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Test pointer export
>
> Id: 0x0000013F2CB60740
> AddressOf: 0x0000013F2C30FE30
> <__main__.PEParserBase object at 0x0000013F2CB60740>
>   hFile: None
>   dwFileSize: 3141593
>   bytes: 2718282
>   fileBuffer: None
>
> Id: 0x0000013F2CBA72B0
> AddressOf: 0x0000000000000000
> <cparam 'P' (0x0000013F2C30FE30)>
>
>   C:
>     Address: 0x13F2C30FE30
>     dwFileSize: 3141593
>     bytes: 2718282
>
> Id: 0x0000013F2CB607C0
> AddressOf: 0x0000013F2CB60808
> <__main__.LP_PEParserBase object at 0x0000013F2CB607C0>
>
> Id: 0x0000013F2CB60AC0
> AddressOf: 0x0000013F2C30FE30
> <__main__.PEParserBase object at 0x0000013F2CB60AC0>
>   hFile: None
>   dwFileSize: 123
>   bytes: 2718282
>   fileBuffer: None
>
>
> Done.
> ```